# replicate existing stored procedure to different database and tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view, datatables

I'm trying to replicate below procedure to my tables but bot able to do for many variables defined need help

have replicated most of the procedure but not able to get the desired output. Below is the SP on a different DB and table

```
USE [GPC_Acquisition]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_GPC_ACQ_PSSQLQry]    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


-- Description : This Procedure populates the GPC_ACQ_PSSQLQry table with SQL query for each of the different peoplesoft record names, these query will be used in the 
-- SSIS package Source to create the output file 
-- for a given Destination table Name like GPC_REP_CustromerMaster. AliasFieldName are used if there are duplicate Fields in the Source table Ex : like Name1
-- Return : None
--execute [dbo].[usp_GPC_ACQ_PSSQLQry] 2,1,'GPC_REP_CustomerMaster'
CREATE procedure [dbo].[usp_GPC_ACQ_PSSQLQry]
(
    @inFileTypeID INT,
    @inACQID INT,
    @inTblName as Varchar(50)
)
AS
Declare @sqlStrVal as varchar(max),
        @lPSRecName as varchar(50),
        @ltblName as varchar(100), --='GPC_Customer_Master',
        @lRcdCnt as INT,
        @i as INT =1,
        @lSrcTblName as varchar(50),
        @lACQID INT,
        @lFileTypeID INT,
        @lSqlWCond  varchar(200)


        SET @ltblName = @inTblName
        SET @lACQID = @inACQID
        SET @lFileTypeID = @inFileTypeID;


        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#StgDefs') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #StgDefs;

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PSTblNames') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #PSTblNames;

-- Creating the List of Fields from StageMetaData Def table for the FileType and AcquisitionID
    with SrcDef
    as
    (
    Select CASE WHEN LEN(SrcFieldNameAlias) >0  THEN SrcFieldNameAlias ELSE  [SrcFieldName] eND [SrcFieldName] ,[SrcFieldDesc],[SequenceNo],
    sdf.FileTypeID,sdf.ACQMasterID,[STG_tableName] from [GPC_ACQ_SrcTblMetaDataDefs]  sdf
    inner join GPC_ACQ_FileType ft on 
    ft.ACQMasterID= sdf.ACQMasterID and ft.FileTypeID= sdf.FileTypeID 
    where  ft.FileTypeID=@lFileTypeID
    ),
    --Selecting the Field list required for the SQL String by linking Stage Field and Dest MetaData Field for the required Desttablename
    --,FileType and ACQID
    CTE_Stg 
    as
    (
    SELECT  ddf.[ACQMasterID],ddf.[FileTypeID],DDF.[slno],
    [SrcFieldName] ,CASE WHEN LEN(DestAliasFieldName) > 0 THEN DestAliasFieldName ELSE DestFieldName END AS DestFieldName,ddf.[DestTableName],ddf.[PeoplesoftRecordName],
    ddf.Defaultvalues,sdf.[STG_tableName]
    FROM SrcDef sdf
    right outer join [vw_GPC_DestMetaDataDefs] ddf on
    sdf.SrcFieldName=CASE WHEN LEN(DestAliasFieldName) > 0 THEN DestAliasFieldName ELSE DestFieldName END
    and sdf.FileTypeID= ddf.FileTypeID and sdf.ACQMasterID= ddf.ACQMasterID
    where  [DestTableName]=@ltblName
    ) 

-- Moving data to Temp table 
-- added distinct as there can be duplicate Fieldnames for diff PS Rec Names
select distinct * into #StgDefs from CTE_Stg


-- Selecting the PSRecord name and Sequence No into Temp table for the Selected Table Name
    Select distinct [PeoplesoftRecordName],DestSequenceNo into #PSTblNames from [vw_GPC_DestMetaDataDefs] where DestTableName=@ltblName 

-- Getting the Source tableName for the Select query 
    select @lSrcTblName=STG_tableName from [dbo].[GPC_ACQ_FileType] where FileTypeID = @lFileTypeID and ACQMasterID = @lACQID

    select @lRcdCnt=count(distinct PeoplesoftRecordName) from #StgDefs

-- Clearing the Existing SQls for the Detination table
    Delete from GPC_ACQ_PSSQLQry where DestTablename=@ltblName


-- Looping Thru the Field List from the Temp table to build the Dynamic Select statement for each of the PSrecordname
--These SQL Strings will be assigned to Variables in the SSIS package
While (@i<=@lRcdCnt)
BEGIN

       SET @sqlStrVal =''
       SET @lSqlWCond =''
       SELECT @lPSRecName= [PeoplesoftRecordName]      from #PSTblNames where DestSequenceNo=@i

       select  @sqlStrVal=@sqlStrVal + case when [SrcFieldName] is null then '''' + DestFieldName  + ''' as '  + DestFieldName else DestFieldName end + ',' 
       from #StgDefs where PeoplesoftRecordName=@lPSRecName  ORDER BY slno

       --SET @sqlStrVal ='Select ' + @sqlStrVal + ' From ' + @lSrcTblName 
       if (@ltblName='GPC_REP_CustomerContact') 
       BEGIN
            SET @sqlStrVal= CASE WHEN CharIndex('GPC_SUB',@sqlStrVal) =0 THEN  @sqlStrVal + 'GPC_SUB,' ELSE  @sqlStrVal END
            SET @sqlStrVal= CASE WHEN  CharIndex('GPC_ACQ_CD',@sqlStrVal) =0 THEN @sqlStrVal + 'GPC_ACQ_CD,' ELSE @sqlStrVal END
            SET @sqlStrVal= CASE WHEN  CharIndex('CUST_ID',@sqlStrVal) =0 THEN @sqlStrVal + 'CUST_ID,' ELSE @sqlStrVal END
       END
          -- remove the last ','
       SELECT @sqlStrVal=LEFT(@sqlStrVal, len(@sqlStrVal)-1)

       -- For Non CRC
       --SET @sqlStrVal ='Select [Slno],FM.FileExecMasterID,CRCID,v.[ACQMasterID],FM.FileTypeID,''' +  @lPSRecName + ''' PSName, ' + @sqlStrVal + ' From ' + @lSrcTblName  +  ' V INNER JOIN  [dbo].[GPC_FileExecMaster] FM on FM.[ACQMasterID]= v.[ACQMasterID]  and FM.[FileExecMasterID]= V.[FileExecMasterID] WHERE V.DataMappingErrorTypeID IS NULL '
       -- For CRC
       SET @sqlStrVal ='Select [Slno],FM.FileExecMasterID,CRCID,v.[ACQMasterID],FM.FileTypeID,UpdateStatus,''' +  @lPSRecName + ''' PSName, ' + @sqlStrVal + ' From ' + @lSrcTblName  +  ' V INNER JOIN  [dbo].[GPC_FileExecMaster] FM on FM.[ACQMasterID]= v.[ACQMasterID]  and FM.[FileExecMasterID]= V.[FileExecMasterID] WHERE V.DataMappingErrorTypeID IS NULL '

       SET @lSqlWCond =CASE WHEN @lPSRecName='PS_GPC_CUS_EXM_STG' THEN  ' AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(TAX_EXEMPT_CERT))) > 0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(ISSUING_AUTHORITY))) >0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(AUTHORITY_TYPE))) > 0) '
                            WHEN @lPSRecName='PS_GPC_CUS_EX_DTL' THEN ' AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(TAX_EXEMPT_CERT))) > 0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(TAX_EXEMPT_FLAG))) >0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(EXEMPT_CATEGORY))) > 0)'
                            WHEN @lPSRecName='PS_GPC_CUS_SIC_CD' THEN ' AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(SIC_CD_QUAL))) > 0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(SIC_CODE))) >0)'
                            WHEN @lPSRecName='PS_GPC_CUS_TEAM_ST' THEN ' AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUPPORT_TEAM_CD))) > 0)'
                            WHEN @lPSRecName='PS_GPC_CUS_VAT_RG' THEN ' AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(VAT_RGSTRN_ID))) > 0 Or LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(COUNTRY_2CHAR))) > 0)'
                            WHEN @lPSRecName='PS_GPC_CUS_VAT_EX' THEN ' AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(COUNTRY_CODE))) > 0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(VAT_EXCPTN_TYPE))) >0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(VAT_EXCPTN_CERTIF))) > 0)'                         
                            WHEN @lPSRecName='PS_GPC_CUS_CG_LNK' THEN ' AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST_GRP_TYPE))) > 0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(CUSTOMER_GROUP))) >0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(DEFAULT_TAX_GRP))) > 0)'
                            WHEN @lPSRecName='PS_GPC_CUS_ID_NBR' THEN ' AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(STD_ID_NUM_QUAL))) > 0 OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(STD_ID_NUM))) >0)' 
                            WHEN @lPSRecName='PS_GPC_CONTACT_STG' THEN ' AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST_Name))) > 0 )' 
                            WHEN @lPSRecName='PS_GPC_CONTCT_CUST' THEN ' AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST_Name))) > 0 )' 
                            WHEN @lPSRecName='PS_GPC_CUS_CNTCT' THEN ' AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST_Name))) > 0 )' 
                            WHEN @lPSRecName='PS_GPC_CUS_CONT_PH' THEN ' AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST_Name))) > 0 )' END


        SET @sqlStrVal = CONCAT(@sqlStrVal,@lSqlWCond)


       INSERT INTO GPC_ACQ_PSSQLQry(ACQMasterID,FileTypeID,PSRecName,DestSequenceNo,SQLStr,DestTableName)
       values(@lACQID,@lFileTypeID,@lPSRecName,@i,@sqlStrVal,@ltblName)

       SET @i=@i +1

END 


GO
```

This is what the DB and table and column names for which i want the SP to be created 
1 st Table name : `[AFG_LOB_DESTTBLMETADATA_DEFS]`

Column names:`[Dest],[lob_master_id],[Division_ID],[File_Type_Id],[Sl_No],[Seq_No],[Dest_field_name],[Dest_Field_Alias],[Dest_Field_desc],[Dest_Data_Type],[Sec_Length],[Is_Required],[Create_Dt],[Create_By],[Update_Dt],[Effective_Start_Date],[Effective_End_Date],[Is_Active]`

2 nd table name :`[AFG_LOB_SrcTblmetaDataDefs]`

Column names: `[SrctbMetaDataDefsID],[LOB_Master_ID],[Division_ID],[File_Type_ID],[Sl_No],[SequenceNo],[SrcFieldName],[SrcFieldNameAlias],[SrcFieldDesc],[SrcDataType],[SecLength],[IsRequired],[CreatedDt],[CreateBy],[Updated_Dt],[EffectiveStartDate],[EffectiveEndDate],[IsActive]`

Comment: I feel like we're missing some of your script here; considering the entire statement above is in a comment block.

Comment: I don't even understand what you're trying to ask.  "Replicate the procedure to my tables"?   "Variables defined need help"?   What does that even mean?

Comment: First is the standard procedure on a different DB and below is the tables for which i want procedure the same way written above how can i  achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no special tool designed to do this in SQL Server.   Here's how I would do it.

1. Open a copy of the entire text of your stored procedure in SSMS.
2. Manually change the USE statement, the tables and columns, variable names, and the name of the stored procedure as desired.
3. Execute the script to create the new stored procedure on the other database.
4. Save As... to save your script to a new file.

Comment: can you help me in changing the table and column names which i have mentioned below in my question please?

Comment: I actually can't.  I have no knowledge of your data, your tables or your business logic.   If you don't know how to do this, you might need to hire a contractor to come in and analyze your needs and do the coding and testing.  This kind of thing can take days and is too broad to be answered in Stack Overflow.